# How can Gröbner bases used to describe discrete probability?

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am working in the field of machine learning, and I have come across a few papers that show relationships between Gröbner bases and discrete probability. So I come here for help.

Can you please explain how can Gröbner bases be used to describe discrete probability?

I have looked at Gröbner bases and I understand the general concepts (and used Maple to calculate a few examples). So it is the link that is missing for me.

Comment: What, exactly, are these papers?

Comment: [This](http://www.springerlink.com/content/j83542h24q561674/) is the one I was looking at. Another is [here](http://www.stat.fi/isi99/proceedings/arkisto/varasto/ricc0071.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a nice introduction here: �Pistone, Giovanni and Riccomagno, Eva and Wynn, Henry, Pistone,

Pistone, Giovanni; Riccomagno, Eva; Wynn, Henry
[Computational commutative algebra in discrete statistics](http://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/books/542984.pdf)